# How to do heteroskedasticity/omitted variable test for logit model?

Tags: econometrics, stata

I am doing an Econometrics project and all the variables we are using are dummies. We are trying to run a probit model to get maximum likelihood; however, we are not sure if we can still conduct usually heteroskedasticity or omitted variable test. For example, the Durbin-Wu-Hausman specification test etc. or do we have to use different test method?

Comment: If all your covariates are dummies, you might consider just running OLS.

Comment: you mean no point in using probit or logit model?

Comment: If the conditional expectations function (CEF) is linear, as it is for a saturated all-dummies model, plain regression will estimate the CEF nicely.

Comment: For the probit model, the variance is a function of the mean (as it is for logit). It is never constant, there is no assumption of homoskedasticity, so no need for test.